# Calculate volume of inequality

Tags: analysis, integration, volume

$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 2\cdot \max(\lvert x\rvert,\lvert y\rvert)^2+z^2\leq 4\}$

Any tips for me anyone?

I made a sketch but what now?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You need to integrate along $z$.  For a given $z$, what is the area parallel to the $xy$ plane?  Your sketch should help you here.  By symmetry, you can integrate from $0$ to $2$ in $z$ and double it.  Your integral is $2\int_0^2 \text{area parallel to xy plane} dz$

Comment: well i have $max(|x|,|y|)\leq \sqrt{\frac{4-z^2}{2}}$ is the rhs my integrand?

Comment: @PaulHaberl:  that is correct.  Now what is the area represented by that range of $x,y$?

Comment: sorry i don't know what you mean. do i only need to calculate $2*\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\frac{4-z^2}{2}}dz$

Comment: @PaulHaberl:  No, $\max(|x|,|y|) \le \sqrt {\frac {4-z^2}2}$ represents a planar region.  In 2D, what does $\max |x|,|y|) \le 3$ represent?  What is its area?

Comment: a square with an area of 36? so it is $(2*\sqrt{2})^2=8$?

Comment: @PaulHaberl:  you have the square concept.  So your integrand is $\left(\sqrt {\frac {4-z^2}2}\right)^2$ because the square shrinks as you go away from $z=0$

Comment: ahh true. thank you for your help and your time :)